# How does "tfa.losses.triplet_semihard_loss" get called?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In Tensorflow addons there are two mentions of the triplet loss one is the base class `tfa.losses.triplet_semihard_loss` and the other is `tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss` which is the child class initialized by the user and in turn implicitly calls the base class. In this chunk of code belonging to the child class:

```
    def __init__(self, margin=1.0, name=None):
        super(TripletSemiHardLoss, self).__init__(
            name=name, reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
        self.margin = margin

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return triplet_semihard_loss(y_true, y_pred, self.margin)
```

I do not understand what's going on with the `call` method, it returns the base class function giving the `y_true` and `y_pred` ndarrays but from where exactly do they originate? According to the Tensorflow docs guide the child class is initialized in the model `compile` statement as:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss())
```

and then the model is fitted as:

```
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=5)
```

the `train_dataset` structure is a tuple containing the embeddings data and the corresponding integer label, but how does the child class realize that this is the data to operate on? and so is the `call` method implicitly called as well?

Answer (score 1):

`__call__` is called when an instance of the class is called.`y_true` and `y_pred` contains the true labels and labels predicted by the model respectively. Tensorflow(tf.keras) internally converts the labels you give to `y_true` as seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1692) and trains on the data using `model.fit()`.
 All `tf.keras` losses are implemented in this form, i.e a function with two arguments `y_true` and `y_pred` as seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L780).